# Python requests causing error on certain urls

Tags: python, python-requests

For some reason when I try to get and process the following url with python-requests I receive an error causing my program to fail.  Other similar urls seems to work fine

```
import requests

test = requests.get('http://t.co/Ilvvq1cKjK')
print test.url, test.status_code
```

What could be causing this URL to fail instead of just producing a 404 status code?

Comment: Isn't `HTTPConnectionPool(host='nasa.gov', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /aeronautics` enough info.? The actual connection to the server is being refused so you can't get a 404 from it...

Comment: That is certainly enough info if I was just processing a single web request, however I am running multiple urls through `requests.get()` and this one causes the program to terminate is there a way around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `requests` library has an exception hierarchy as listed [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#exceptions)

So wrap your GET request in a try/except block:

```
import requests

try:
    test = requests.get('http://t.co/Ilvvq1cKjK')
    print test.url, test.status_code
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print e.request.url, "*connection failed*"
```

That way you end up with similar behaviour to what you're doing now (so you get the redirected url), but cater for not being able to connect rather than print the status code.